# How can I add parameters to url in controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, parameters

I'm trying to add parameters to the url but I got a proxy error when I redirect to the same link but with added paramters. I need to add them server side, any idea?

Original url = mysite.com/app

Desired url =  mysite.com/app?signedin=true&color=#ff3000

Thanks for any help

EDIT

The error by cloud9

```
ECONNRESET: Request could not be proxied!
There was an error proxying the request.
```

my code

```
@url =  request.base_url + request.original_fullpath
if @url.include?('?app=true') && user_signed_in?
  redirect_to request.base_url + request.original_fullpath + '&username=#{current_user.username}' + '&username=#{current_user.username}'
else 
...................
respond_to do |format|
 format.html
 format.js
end
```

SOLUTION

It's looping because url with paramter is the same as without one.
What I did is I added a new parameter and made sure that in the if statement it shouldn't be included

Comment: Can you post some code? (basically the stuff you have tried so far)

Comment: I think its looping because I'm basically redirecting to the same link, right?

Comment: Any particular reason why you are doing that?. Also you are missing the `?` when you add `params` , it should be `@url + '?username=#{current_user.username}'`

Comment: working fine now, see my update, not missing anything just a typo while cleaning the code